# Restricting method call to a specific class(within an interface scope)

Tags: java, interface

Is there a way to create an interface with restricted access to particular method?

**Example:**

```
public interface MyInterface {

    /*
     * I want to restrict access to this(and only this) method so only 1 specific class 
     * can call it. Is there a way of doing that? 
     */
    public void setComponent(Component);

    ...other methods...

}
```

**EDIT:**

something like:

```
public default void setComponent(Component component) {
    StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    if(!stacktrace[1].getClassName().equals("MyClassName")){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method should not be called explicitly");
    }
}
```

may do the trick but this will be overridden later so this wont really solve the issue.

Comment: Seems that your code design is initally wrong. Could you please provide more context? Show us a sample implementation of your interface (including how that `Component` should be used afterwards).

Comment: I can't see any use of `component` in you method implementation.

Comment: @TagirValeev It most certainly is wrong. the whole program is messy as hell, but i have only restricted access to it. The implementing class is a  custom Input listener(key bindings) which has a `Component` for the source, an instance if it is passed to some other `Object` witch should set the `Component` but only if that `Object` is an instance of a particular class. In short a random user should not be able to set the source `Component` for the Input class. 
PS: I know this is confusing but this is the best i can do to explain the situation(sorry)

Comment: You can mark setComponent(Component component) in your impl class  as final to avoid being overridden.

Comment: @AmitParashar **No** you cant do that within an `Interface`! besides the method should be overridden.

Comment: I said only impl class.

Comment: @AmitParashar oh.. missed that, sry. But this wont help, this should be done from withing the `Interface` the implementing class is created by a random user and he should not have access to it. As @TagirValeev said it is a pour design... so I'm working on a whole new aproach to this.

Comment: no problem, I understand this is not a good design.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is **No**. Because by default methods in `Interface` are public. If you want to implement, make `Abstract` class and declare method as `protected`:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {


    protected void setComponent(Component);

    ...other methods...

}
```

Comment: I'm aware I can redesign it to extend from a class but that is not the best solution for me. I was hoping for something like maybe tracking the stack trace and find the caller class from within the interface. Problem with that is i must implement a default body which will be overriden so it wont really solve the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `tracking the stack trace and find the caller class from within the interface`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraiding your method get overriden, use final, then in the end of your setCompomonet(), call a new abstract protected method, like realSetCompoment().

Comment: This answer need to be improved.

Comment: @Envil sorry,i'm new here. is this ok now?